# Cordova/Phonegap navigator.camera.getPicture() not returning URL in success() when mediaType set to VIDEO

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to cordova. I tried following code get video URL,

```js
 var pictureSource;
 var destinationType;
 var mediaType;

 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

 function onDeviceReady() {
   pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
   destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
   mediaType = navigator.camera.MediaType;
 }

 navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
   destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
   mediaType: mediaType.VIDEO,
   sourceType: source
 });

 function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
   alert(imageURI);
 }

 function onFail(message) {
   alert(message);
 }
```

When mediaType is excluded the code works fine for Picture upload. But when it is set VIDEO alert() displays nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the content of `mediaType` in your `onDeviceReady()` function?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Do you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Michael : No,I had some other priority tasks so had to put it on hold. Please inform me if manage to get it work.

Comment: @Beat : in onDeviceReady() mediaType is set to "navigator.camera.MediaType" and further I've used it to set mediaType as VIDEO in getPicture().

Comment: You can try following code to get source of video:-

function captureError(e) {
    console.log("capture error: "+JSON.stringify(e));
}

function captureSuccess(s) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(s));
   
}

navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 1});